# readAsDataURL() to change it to image url

Tags: javascript

I have created and molded a function for uploading multiple image files and just stuck in picReader.readAsDataURL(file); which is creating a huge value of an image. as I want this image to be uploaded in my DB

Actually, its a done function just need to reduce the size of value

```
window.onload = function() {
    //Check File API support
    if(window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader)
    {
        var filesInput = document.getElementById("files");

        filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event){

            var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
            var output = document.getElementById("event-img-result");

            //for(var i = 0; i< files.length; i++)
            for(var i = 0; i<=5; i++)
            {
                var file = files[i];

                //Only pics
                if(!file.type.match('image'))
                  continue;

                var picReader = new FileReader();

                picReader.addEventListener("load",function(event){

                    var picFile = event.target;

                    var div = document.createElement("div");

                    div.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
                            "title='" + picFile.name + "'/><input type='hidden' value='" + picFile.result + "'/><a href='javascript:;'>x</a>";

                    output.insertBefore(div,null);            

                });

                 //Read the image
                picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }                               

        });
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by _reduce the size of value_. Do you mean the size of the image files is too large?

Comment: That is correct i want to reduce the size of value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to reduce the file size of your image data would be to reduce the resolution of the original image, and/or encode the image data as a JPEG, in the browser and via the [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API). You could then upload the image data of the image with reduced resolution to your database.

This could integrate with your code is as follows, where the `dataUrl` variable shown below contains the data of the reduced image that should be suitable for storage in your database:

```js
var filesInput = document.getElementById("files");

filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event) {

  var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
  var output = document.getElementById("event-img-result");

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];

    //Only pics
    if (!file.type.match('image'))
      continue;

    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const orignalImg = new Image();

    orignalImg.onload = function() {

      // Quarter the resolution of the image to reduce it's overall file size
      const newWidth = orignalImg.width * 0.25;
      const newHeight = orignalImg.height * 0.25;

      // Set dimensions of canvas to set dimensions of output image
      canvas.width = newWidth
      canvas.height = newHeight

      // Draw scaled orignal image into canvas
      context.drawImage(orignalImg, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

      // imgSmallData contains image data for the reduced file size
      const imgSmallData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

      // Create new image element to demonstrate the technique 
      const imgSmall = new Image()
      imgSmall.src = imgSmallData
      document.body.append(imgSmall)
    }

    orignalImg.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="files" type="file" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The thing i do not understand is about picReader.readAsDataURL(file); that generate value of image how i do not want that i want to image url

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry I don't quite understand - can you please rephrase your question?

Comment: Sure, my function is actually a working function and it is doing a job. My question is when I preview image value like in your code when you upload an image it gives you image value which is I think an image code. Can I just image name or URL instead of this value="image code" ? is it possible. thank you for your help.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like to extract a URL (or path) for the image selected by the user, and use that to upload the image to your database, rather than uploading the image data in `picFile.result` (or `imgSmallData` as in my code snippet)? 
The general answer is "no", you will need to upload the image via the data stored in `imgSmallData`. Hope that helps

Comment: Dacre Denny: Absolutely correct that is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you :-)